# Show the expression for the slope of the secant line $y=x^2 +3x$

Tags: calculus

Show that the expression for the slope of the secant line through $y=x^2 + 3x$ at $x=3$ and $x=3+h$ is msec=$9+h$.

I think I'm supposed to write it in the form of $f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$.

I found that when $x=3$, $y=18$.

I calculated the derivative of the function, $f'(3)$ using limits when $h$ approaches $0$ and ended up with $54$. From there I got $x^2 +3x-54=0$. I factored it and got $x=6$, and $x=-9$.

So now I have the points: $(3,18), (6,54)$ and $(-9,54)$. I found the equation of the secant line that passes through the points $(3,18)$ and $(-9,54)$ to be $y=-3x+27$, and the slope to be $-3$.

I think I have the material I need in order to answer the question, but the wording of the question is really confusing me.

Your help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You are given a function $y=x^2+3x$ and asked to find the slope of the secant line connecting the two points at $x=3$ and $x=3+h$.

When $x=3$ we have $y=3^2+3*3=18$

When $x=3+h$ we have $y=(3+h)^2+3(3+h)=9+6h+h^2+9+3h=h^2+9h+18$

You therefore need to calculate the slope of the line connecting the points $(3,18)$ and $(3+h,h^2+9h+18)$

Hopefully you know how to do this.